# How to check if object contains a string value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I know can read values inside the object as the h tags get populated, but I can't hit the statements checking `response.image` for a value, even though my console.log shows that it does exist.

I'm not sure whether the below is the correct semantics to check for a value. I presume I might need to do it before the return statement. Hitting `response.result.image` is fine, but I presume it's because I'm not checking for a string value like the other 2 statements above.

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import getResponse from '../Handler/getResponse.jsx';
import Spinner from '../Spinner/Spinner.jsx';

import './Modal.css';

 const Modal = ({close, item}) => {
    const response = getResponse(item);
    console.log(response);

    return (
        <div>
           {response === null &&(<Spinner/>)}
            {response &&(
                <div className='modal'>
                <div className='popup'>
                    <h1>{response.result.name}</h1>
                    <h5>{response.result.description}</h5>
                    {(response.image === "Error") &&(
                        <p className="text">{response.result.detailedDescription.articleBody}</p>
                    )}
                   {response.image && (response.image !== "Error") &&(
                     <div className="container">
                                <div className="left">{response.result.detailedDescription.articleBody}</div>
                        <div className="right"><img className="image" alt="image" src={response.image}/></div>
                     </div>
                   )}
                   {response.result.image &&(
                     <div className="container">
                        <div className="left">{response.result.detailedDescription.articleBody}</div>
                        <div className="right"><img className="image" alt="image" src={response.result.image.contentUrl}/></div>
                     </div>
                   )}
                   <button onClick={ () => { close(false) }}>close me</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
        </div>
   );
}

export default Modal;
```

Comment: Can you clarify which value is not giving you what you expect?  Or somehow ask this more directly?

Comment: @jmargolisvt I've changed the title, but essentially I'm trying to check if `response.image`  contains the string "Error" for the first statement, and for the 2nd one to render something else when it doesn't contain "Error" but an actual image URL.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one I think you forgot the data key in your response, but I can't be sure as I don't have getResponse() function?

```
import React from 'react';
import getResponse from '../Handler/getResponse.jsx';
import Spinner from '../Spinner/Spinner.jsx';

import './Modal.css';

 const Modal = ({close, item}) => {
    const r = getResponse(item);
    const response = r.data;

    console.log(response);


    // You can check if it is string with this one;
   if (typeof response.image === 'String' && response.image !== '') {
     console.log('String exists and is not empty')
   }

    return (
        <div>
           {response === null &&(<Spinner/>)}
            {response &&(
                <div className='modal'>
                <div className='popup'>
                    <h1>{response.result.name}</h1>
                    <h5>{response.result.description}</h5>
                    {(response.image === "Error") &&(
                        <p className="text">{response.result.detailedDescription.articleBody}</p>
                    )}
                   {response.image && (response.image !== "Error") &&(
                     <div className="container">
                                <div className="left">{response.result.detailedDescription.articleBody}</div>
                        <div className="right"><img className="image" alt="image" src={response.image}/></div>
                     </div>
                   )}
                   {response.result.image &&(
                     <div className="container">
                        <div className="left">{response.result.detailedDescription.articleBody}</div>
                        <div className="right"><img className="image" alt="image" src={response.result.image.contentUrl}/></div>
                     </div>
                   )}
                   <button onClick={ () => { close(false) }}>close me</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
        </div>
   );
}

export default Modal;
```